# Syntax error on Jquery form post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this code below which is suppose to be submitting a form via Jquery's post.

```
<script>
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {
  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();
  /* get some values from elements on the page: */
  var $form = $( this ),
      url = $form.attr( 'action' );

  /* Serialize Data */
  var senddata = $form.serializeArray();

  /* Send the data using post */
  var posting = $.post( url, senddata);

  /* Put the results in a div */
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = $( data ).find( '#content' );
    $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
  });
});
</script>
```

But every time I try and submit I get this error in the console:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Array ( [name] => name [email] => dsf@dsfsd.com [number] => 23456567 [query] => query )

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: That error looks very much like a PHP error. Are you sure the problem isn't on the server?

Comment: What line throws this error?

Comment: It may be due to the data coming back from the php file. I'm just testing something.

Comment: Mike put me on the right track. It was the post back from the PHP file that was causing the issue when trying to parse it back into an object. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try changing posting to:

```
var posting = $.post( url, { 'data' : senddata} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Mike put me on the right track. It was the post back from the PHP file that was causing the issue when trying to parse it back into an object. Thanks for your help guys